# google react-places-autocomplete api restrict search suggestions to Australia / single country

Tags: reactjs

Hello I want to limit my search suggestions (and therefore limit a user to choose an Australian address) with react places autocomplete to addresses from Australia, and to note I have checked stack overflow for similar questions and none of them seem to work, here is an example of the suggestions I am currently getting that i would like to be only Australian Suggestions.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL40q.png)

here is what i think is the relevant code

import PlacesAutocomplete, {
geocodeByAddress,
getLatLng,
} from 'react-places-autocomplete';

```
<PlacesAutocomplete
        fullWidth
        className="search-bar"
        value={address}
        onChange={setAddress}
        onSelect={handleSelect}
       
      
      >
        {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (
         
          <div   >



            <input
            style={{width:"100%" }}
              {...getInputProps({
                placeholder: 'Enter Job Address',
                className: 'location-search-input',
              })}
            />
            <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container"

             key={suggestions.description}
            >
              {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
              {suggestions.map((suggestion, index)=> {
                const className = suggestion.active
                  ? 'suggestion-item--active'
                  : 'suggestion-item';
                // inline style for demonstration purpose
                const style = suggestion.active
                  ? { backgroundColor: '#fafafa', cursor: 'pointer' }
                  : { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer' };
                return (
                  
                  <div
                  key={index}
                    {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                      className,
                      style,
                    })}
                  >
                    <span>{suggestion.description }</span>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </PlacesAutocomplete>
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this prop

searchOptions={{componentRestrictions: { country: ['au'] }}}